# GlassFish v3 in Eclipse shows "Wrong username or password" after starting

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

During the GlassFish installation I have chosen user name and password. These parameters are properly set on the Eclipse Server Adapter setting page. But when I start GlassFish in debug mode from Eclipse, I get "Wrong username and password".

There is nothing in the server log - in fact the server is started and works properly. The message only appears something like 95% of the time, and it is making debugging of the application problematic with the constant restarts and redeploys.

Anybody found how to overcome this problem?

I am using Oracle GlassFish Server 3.0.1 and Eclipse Helios Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers (Helios Service Release 1 Build id: 20100917-0705).

Answer (score 23):

For me the fix was to leave the "Password" field empty. I am however using different versions (but I stumbled upon this thread and maybe someone else will see this as well) of Eclipse and GlassFish(Eclipse Kepler & GlassFish 4.0).

I hope this helps anybody.

EDIT putting together compatibility of this fix from the comments:

<kbd>Kepler & 4.0</kbd>
<kbd>Luna & 4.1</kbd>
<kbd>Mars & 4.1</kbd>

Comment: A true lifesaver. As simple as that.

Comment: Possibly, in GF4 the password does not get saved on install. I started the server with a blank password and the used the admin console to change it. The Kepler server status immediately showed Stopped invalid user name password. I Then set the password in the properties, and the status changed back to Started.

Comment: @destan - same setup. worked for me. But, what if your company requires you to have a password for the server ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Then, I guess you need to configure GlassFish outside the eclipse, deal with some config file and so... But not sure how exactly

Comment: didnt think of this. this should be higher! gj m8!

Comment: This works for Eclipse Mars and Glassfish 4.1 as well.

Answer (score 18):

I had this problem too. For me the solution was to disable the "Use Anonymous Connection for Admin Commands" option. To do so, follow these steps:

- Right click on the Glassfish entry in the Server tab and click "Open" from the context menu. (Or press F3 while the Glassfish entry is selected.)
- Make sure the box "Use Anonymous Connection for Admin Commands" is unselected, see the screenshot.

  [image: The red arrow points to the box that has to be checked.]
- Don't forget to save before you retry...

Comment: that worked for me. seriously, what kind of as*hole put that option in by default when i explicitly tell glassfish to use username and pass when at the configuration wizzard.

Comment: I had the same problem and unchecking the option "Use Anonymous...." solved the problem for me. Weird!

Comment: Same problem here too and unchecking it solved it for me. Perhaps you mean uncheck the "Use Anonymous..." ?

Comment: So this answer was first posted 2011-08-01, over two years ago. And the problem is still present (anonymous connection is default) in the latest Eclipse build that was compiled 2013-02-07.

Comment: @MartinAndersson - I am the unlucky guy. This did NOT work for me. Searching for a solution.

Answer (score 9):

If the log refers to full host names, like:

> JMXService URL = service:jmx:rmi://my-work-pc.lan:8686/jndi/rmi://my-work-pc.lan:8686/jmxrmi

rather than, for example:

> JMXService URL = service:jmx:rmi://localhost:8686/jndi/rmi://localhost:8686/jmxrmi

...then disabling the proxy settings in Eclipse (Preferences, General, Network Connections, Active Provider: Direct) might solve it.

For what I've read the default "Native" proxy setting yields problems as GlassFish by default binds to `0.0.0.0`, which causes host name resolution rather than simply "localhost" in the RMI calls above. Given the host name it then finds, Eclipse might then feel it needs to use your proxy (if set) even for what is actually localhost.

Comment: servers - glassfish - glassfish - view logfile. I saw the same problem you mentioned. But, after following your steps i still get the error. Restarting eclipse did not help.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was just disable Anonymous Connection for Admin Commands. Auto deploy is another silly enabled default option because on every save freezes eclipse for a while, of course this does not count on small projects so you are good if you are writing only Hello world projects :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while setting up glassfish4 with eclipse. Below setting resolved the issue:

1. Keep username as "admin" with a blank password (Unless you changed
   anything while installation).
2. Select  - 'Use Anonymous Connection for Admin Commands' checkbox.

   [image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the problem is removed when auto-deploy  after changes option is removed.

Answer (score 0):

For the first time from your eclipse do not set any username and password as @mgttlinger said. i hope now you can start the server without any issue.

1. Open admin console by localhost:4848(not it wont ask any credential)
2. To set admin password, go to Domain -> Administrator Password
3. Enter New Password and Confirm New Password.
4. Click on Save button
5. Restart the server
6. Try access localhost:4848(now you have to enter username and password to login admin console)

In Eclipse also set username as admin and given password to access glassfish server from your eclipse

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is Windows, and your Glassfish installation location is in root directory (e.g. C:\dev\tool\Glassfish ), then try run Eclipse "as administrator", believe it or not, I know its a bit weird, that does solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem , did restore default to remove the password set at the time of server installation in eclipse. The server started after that.