# GlassFish in Eclipse complains "GlassFish v3 requires a JDK 1.6 and not a JRE"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, glassfish

I am running:

- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
- Version: Helios Service Release 2
- Build id: 20110218-0911

I have also installed Java EE 6 SDK Update 2 which includes:

- GlassFish Open Source Edition 3.1
- Java EE 6 Code Samples
- Java EE 6 API Documentation
- Java EE 6 Tutorial
- Your First Cup: An Introduction to the Java EE Platform

I have registered GlassFish with Eclipse but when I try to start the server, I get the following error:

> GlassFish v3 requires a JDK 1.6 and not a JRE. Please add/select the correct JDK in the Server properties 'Runtime Environment' section.

I have searched here for an answer but none so far seem to work. Can anybody suggest how I would sort this error out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you downloaded (or pointed Eclipse to) a JRE, but it needs a JDK.  The latter has all the Java tools: javac.exe, java.exe, jar.exe, etc.

If you look at the directory where you told Eclipse to look for a JDK, you must see a /bin directory with those .exe files in it.  If you don't, you know why the error message.

Make sure you downloaded a JDK and point Eclipse to it.

One more check: see if you can start Glassfish without Eclipse.  You're ignorant of two things if you're learning both at the same time.  Leave one unknown out of the equation until you can make Glassfish run on its own.

You need a JAVA_HOME environment variable.  What's it pointing to?  If you don't have one, create it.

Comment: under "Installed JRE's", I had to point to the JDK and not the JRE. Worked fine, thanks.

Comment: Definitely. Try first Netbeans Ee edition as it comes with Glassfish.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue and actually i got the solution from this link ( The above answers really didnt gave me the solution

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=7033028

1) make sure the jdk is installed. Look in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.XXXX (mine says 0_16). If that has stuff in it the jdk probably was installed, if not you can grab just the jdk from http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp

2) This is where the error message kinda foobars ya... 
- Get eclipse started, ignore the message. 
- Go to Window>Preferences 
- Then under +Java+Installed JREs hit Add.
- Select 'Standard VM' then Next
- JRE Home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.XXXX the rest should fill in automagically. Hit Finish.
- MOST IMPORTANT!!! Click the check box back in the Preferences Window for the new jdk runtime...I don't know why it's necessary, but it definitely is...

3)Still in Preference Window.
- Get to +Server, Runtime Environments
- Select the Glassfish SRE, hit Edit...
- From the JRE drop down grab the JDK and hit Finish
- Hit Okay.

4)Go to the Servers Veiw (probably down by the Console View).
Right click on the Bundled Glassfish...Server and hit restart/start...

Comment: +1 For a detailed answer. Good job preetha ! Thanks. JDK is necessary as per error. A small variation for me just after point 2. You will not see the stuff of point 3. After 2, close and restart your eclipse. Then follow step 3. That will solve this problem.

Comment: Avoid creating a password for your glassfish during the steps. Reason - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102331/glassfish-v3-in-eclipse-shows-wrong-username-or-password-after-starting

Answer (score 11):

For other people like me who still have a problem, try to be careful in your JRE Definition :

Don't use this : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre`

but this : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29`

and Glassfish will eventually work.

Answer (score 7):

It took me a while to find where this is configured in eclipse so I'll note it here for everyone:

Window menu > Preferences dialog > Server section > Runtime Environments subsection.

Comment: Or: double-click the server (or select it and press F3) and then click the link to Runtime Environment, to get to the very same settings.