# Glassfish server jdk not found

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, ide, java-6

I am going to setup glassfish with eclipse. Glassfish server has installed with eclipse but now when i tried to run any jsp , it shows this error.
**"GlassFish v3 requires a JDK 1.6 and not a JRE. Please add/select the correct JDK in the Server properties 'Runtime Environment' section."**
I searched alot and I have seen these [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638748/glassfish-in-eclipse-doesnt-seem-to-see-my-jdk) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082936/glassfish-in-eclipse-complains-glassfish-v3-requires-a-jdk-1-6-and-not-a-jre) questions too but unable to find the solution. Please can anyone tell me that why this problem is occurring and its step by step solution?
Please keep in mind that i have installed java7 so is this due to java7 as it is asking for jdk1.6.
 I am thinking that it would be 1.6 or up versions.
thanks

Comment: which flavor of eclipse you are using?

Comment: What OS, what's your CLASSPATH, and where did you install the jdk?

Comment: os is WINDOWS and classpath is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin"- i set my classpath in My Computer -> properties -> environmental variables -> ....

Comment: Your CLASSPATH is incorrect: 1. it should be CLASSPATH, not classpath - I don't know if Windows cares, but all the other OSes do so it's probably good to do it right. 2. You've given the path to your bin directory, not the location of your rt.jar and other runtime classes and jars.  3. I probably should have asked you what your PATH was set to as well.

Comment: Do you have another JRE installed, except the one in your JDK?

Comment: This is my PATH variable value, I haven't set my CLASSPATH

Comment: no @Traroth i have only jre7 and jdk1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Actually the problem was that eclipse was not able to find the jdk as glassfish needs jdk to run files(not only jre). So when i edited this then I am able to run  successfully :). This [link](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=7033028) helped me alot

Comment: Because i was unable to find all the steps that i needed to create lookup for eclipse to jdk

Answer (score 0):

make sure the jdk is installed. Look in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.XXXX (mine says 0_16). If that has stuff in it the jdk probably was installed, if not you can grab just the jdk from http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp

This is where the error message kinda foobars ya.

Get eclipse started, ignore the message.
Go to Window>Preferences
Then under +Java+Installed JREs hit Add.
Select Standard VM then Next

JRE Home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.XXXX the rest should fill in automagically. Hit Finish.
MOST IMPORTANT! Click the check box back in the Preferences Window for the new jdk runtime...I don't know why it's necessary, but it definitely is...
Still in Preference Window. (May have to hit Okay, and re-open Preference window)

Get to +Server, Runtime Environments
Select the Glassfish SRE, hit Edit...
From the JRE drop down grab the JDK and hit Finish
Hit Okay.
Go to the Servers Veiw (probably down by the Console View). Right click on the Bundled Glassfish...Server and hit restart/start